# How to trigger different Azure CD pipelines depending on git branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The environment which I'm deploying to has 3 stages

- dev
- uat
- production

The git repository for the project has dev and main branches.
On push to dev, the CI pipeline runs, creates an image and pushes the image to a registry.
Next the CD release pipeline is triggered and auto deploys to the dev environment.

I want the next stage to be triggered by the merge from dev to main,
so I can't see how I can use the same CD pipeline - I'd love to be shown that this is actually possible.

So for now, I'm going with 2 CI pipelines and 2 cd pipelines as follows:

- dev-branch

  - CI (auto triggered by push to dev)
  - CD

    - dev-stage (auto triggered by CI above)
- main-branch

  - CI (auto triggered by push to main)
  - CD

    - uat-stage (auto triggered by CI above)
    - prod-stage

The problem that I'd like to solve with this setup is :
can this be done with a single CI pipeline, suppressing the CD pipeline runs based on the source branch in git which triggered the build?

My CI pipeline yaml is as follows, I'd like to use this one file for both main and dev,
rather than having to duplicate it with the only difference being the individual triggers for dev and main.

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - main

variables:
- group: devops-project-group
- template: app-variables.yml

pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
- bash: |
    echo 'starting build ...'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditions:

```
- bash: |
    echo 'starting MASTER build ...'
  condition: and(succeeded(), variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
```

alternatively you can do `ifs`:

```
steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
  - bash: master step1
  - bash: master step2
  etc
${{ else }}:
  - bash: dev step1
  - bash: dev step2
  etc
-
```

or you can determine branch in the bash step and do something accordingly